# How do I get a SlingBox/SlingPlayer working?

Tags: 10.10, video-player

How can I get my SlingPlayer/SlingBox setup to work on my 10.10 install?  I don't know if using Wine will work or if VM will work.  This is almost the only reason I flip back to Windows on my Dual Boot Machine.  Thanks.

Comment: Since you have dual boot, you can try it first and then tell us if you have a problem?

Answer (score 1):

A VM should certainly work, I've used it for SlingPlayer in the past and there were no problems.

There is also evidence that you can get the player going with Wine on Ubuntu:

See:  http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=14848&iTestingId=53229

The test results are for 10.04, but you should have similar results with 10.10.

If you're not very comfortable with Wine, you can take a look at the commercial adaptation of Wine, called CrossOver.  Here is their page on SlingPlayer 2.0 compatibility:

http://www.codeweavers.com/compatibility/browse/name/?app_id=5611

Comment: @steabert - I tried Wine prior to asking the question. However I could not get the install to finish successfully. Thus my question.   @Mark Russell - Thank you for the suggestion regarding CrossOver.  I will try that and post my results for future user queries.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use genymotion and virtualbox to install Android emulated device(s) on Ubuntu, then install slingplayer in the usual way from the google app store (you'll have to pay for it though).  I'm on ubuntu 12.04 fyi.  The incentive though is that you will get a full-featured slingmobile player complete with online program guide etc. which afaik you can't get with any other method of putting sling on linux (facebook app also does not provide program guide).  I will just note also that the sound delivery can have some issues with the genymotion vm's and sometimes vm has to be restarted.  Still, it's another way.  Here's how you setup genymotion:  http://linuxicle.blogspot.com/2013/10/install-genymotion-in-linuxubuntu-1304.html

In my case, I selected the "Nexus One - 4.2.2 - with Google Apps API 17" VM.  You just start it up, purchase slingplayer from the app store, and go.  I find when the VM is full screen my wireless has hard time delivering steady picture and sound, so I keep it smallish and it runs pretty good.  Your mileage may very, enjoy.